# Jquery to find how a letter is decorated

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, styles

```
<p id='mytxt'>This <i>is</i> <b>a <i>pen.</i></b></p>
```

With jQuery, how can I find how a particular letter in the given html is decorated?

E.g., How can I find the 11<sup>th</sup> letter is `"p"`, and it is slanted and bold?

What I'd like to do is to copy the html into an Excel cell without using clipboard. The code would be something like the following:

```
var str = $('mytxt').text();
objExcel.Range("A1").value = str
for( var i=0; i<str.length(); i++ ){
  var bold = [code to find whether the i-th letter is bold]; // TRUE / FALSE
  var italic = [code to find whether the i-th letter is italic]; // TRUE / FALSE
  objExcel.Range("A1").Characters(i,1).Bold = bold;
  objExcel.Range("A1").Characters(i,1).Italic = italic;
}
```

Comment: First, Why you want find p?

Comment: okay, to be a bit clearer what do you want the input to be and what do you want the output to be?

Comment: edited my question to clarify what I want to do. Hope it made my question clearer.

Answer (score 0):

In case your text is like of

```
<p id="myTxt">This <span id="italicFont">is</span> <span id="boldFont">a<span id="italicFont">pen</span></span></p>
```

then Try this code may helps to style your code

```
  <script>
    $( "#mytxt").find( "span #italickFont" ).css( " font-style", "italic" );
    $( "#mytxt").find( "span #boldFont" ).css( " font-style", "bold" );
    </script>
```